# Linear modular equalities with $0/1$ solution

Tags: linear-algebra, dc.parallel-comp

Let $Ax\equiv b\bmod q$ be a $n\times n$ modular linear system known to have $0/1$ solution where $q$ is a large prime. We can solve in $NC^2$ for general linear systems using determinant and matrix inverse computations.

Can the above be solved in $NC^1$?